# So many games So little time!

Tags: riddle, video-games

So here's yet another game that I used to play... way to much.

> I might not be a superbeast,
>
> But Rob's name holds what I fight at least.
>
> They're good at leaping, singing, reaping and many more,
>
> Once you know them all you'll be less sore.
>
> Be carefull using weapons that you find,
>
> Because noise is what makes them go out off their mind.
>
> What once was seen from above,
>
> Soon from the FRONT to top it off.
>
> I must be brave
>
> the farther I walk out the lesser it is safe.
>
> But it's a chance I take,
>
> For the rewards that I will make.

What is the name of the game that I'm referring to?

EDIT HINT:

> In this game you could choose between single and multiplayer, because sometimes enabling multiplayer made the games unplayable hard.

HINT 2:

> 'Soon From the FRONT' has become now (05/09/2018).

Comment: I'm thinking something about kirby.... like kirby dreamland 3

Comment: @Duck no, it's nothing like that :p.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing:

> Resident Evil (series)

I might not be a superbeast, But Rob's name holds what I fight at least.

> As @SteveV pointed out, this refers to zombies

They're good at leaping, singing, reaping and many more, Once you know them all you'll be less sore.

> The series features many zombie and creature types, and figuring out their respective habits help a lot in your survival odds

Be carefull using weapons that you find, Because noise is what makes them go out off their mind.

> Again as pointed out by @SteveV, noisy weapons draw attention to the player

What once was seen from above, Soon from the FRONT to top it off.

> The series started as a third-person shooter, but its recent instalments have been first-person instead.

I must be brave the farther I walk out the lesser it is safe.

But it's a chance I take, For the rewards that I will make.

> Guessing this refers to how zombies get tougher as you go but you have to wander out anyway for the ultimate reward - survival.

For the record, I also thought that the

> Left 4 Dead series

may have been a good answer, but went with this instead because it has more titles in the series, which matches the puzzle title "So many games, so little time".

Comment: Both guesses are wrong, however the third person to first person is correct. Resident Evil series was a nice guess, really loved the games.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the idea, but maybe not the right one.  But is it:

> Dead Nation, the video game?

But Rob's name holds what I fight at least.

> That would be Rob Zombie and you fight zombies

They're good at leaping, singing, reaping and many more,

> some of the zombies leap from across the screen, some scream (sing?) to call other zombies

Be carefull using weapons that you find,
Because noise is what makes them go out off their mind.

> some weapons (grenades, etc) attract more zombies

What once was seen from above,

> Top-view shooter game

Soon from the FRONT to top it off.

> not sure, perhaps further in it goes to first person shooter?

I must be brave
the farther I walk out the lesser it is safe.
But it's a chance I take,
For the rewards that I will make.

> The zombies get harder as you go along your path, but you need to do so to move forward in the game.

Comment: It's not the right game but you are on the correct trail. Rob Zombie and you fight zombies is correct. 'What once was seen from above' its' a top-view shooter would also be correct and yes the zombies do get harder the farther you go.